# Weird Characters on Webpage

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters, character

I'm getting product descriptions from Amazon web service and storing them in MySQL. I've noticed that, for some characters, what is stored in the database is not the same as what is displayed on my webpage. For example, the hyphen `-` is showing as `â€”`. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're storing UTF and reading as something else like latin-1. (A character in UTF-8 can be encoded in more than one byte.)

Comment: ... or you might be reading it correctly as UTF-8, but your HTML page contains an incorrect content-type that specifies a non-UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try adding the following code in your html `<head>` section:

`<meta charset="utf-8" />`

And reading a bit about [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is worth too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your webserver is using the right char encoding too. I had problems in the past with æøå (on danish websites) and just setting a charset in the html isn't enough if the server isn't set to use the right charset.